# Removing title before attributes in Google Earth Pro

Tags: qgis, convert, google-earth

How can I remove the repetition of the title in the attribute table of Google Earth Pro?

[image]

I converted a XLSX file into a CSV. Then I put the CSV in QGIS and converted into KML. The KML I imported in Google Earth Pro. And when I click on the location, the attributes appear but there also appears the title of the document before each attribute. How can I remove it?